# How to know selected text with C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Can someone tell me how to read selected text with C#?
I need it to work outside of my app.
For example, the user opens a Notepad, writes something, selects text, and presses a hotkey.
I need to store the text in a variable in my program. How can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Notepad does not have an API for doing this. Just use a `RichTextBox` control or similar to hold the required text document...

Comment: Notepad is just an example, i need a low-level method to read it whatever the program is.

Comment: Have a look at [How to get selected text from an active application, without using a clipboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532221/how-to-get-selected-text-from-an-active-application-without-using-a-clipboard) and [catch selected text outside my application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you could read the text from a notepad window via PInvoke. SendMessage function from user32.dll...
Here is a example http://loyaltyhf.blogspot.com/2013/01/source-chrome-class.html that reads the address from Google Chrome's Address bar. It might not work for the current version of Google Chrome but it'll give you a pretty good idea.